# Put my ads on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

What I'm searching is a way so I could put my campaigns (ads) on an advertisement inside an iphone app just like I use google dfp to submit my campaigns to my site.

How can I do this on an iphone app ? Is the google admob the right tool for this job ; I had a look, and I saw the new campaign function but I think is for google adwords campaing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Apple's iAds service? It embeds ads right into a plethora of iPhone apps already created with iAds enabled to run within them. I don't believe google ads can be displayed in iPhone apps.